# Android: assocation with file (working with opened file)

Tags: java, android

I made file's association with my app:

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:mimeType="application/zip" />
        <data android:mimeType="application/rar" />
        <data android:mimeType="application/7z" />
    </intent-filter>
```

It works, but it just opens the main activity.

How can I get opened file and manipulate with it in my app?

P.S. Why association with 7z doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like that:

```
filePath = getIntent().getData().getEncodedPath();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Uri uri = intent.getData();
String filePath = uri.getPath(); // do not use uri.getEncodedPath() this is important
File file = new File(filePath);
```

Association with 7z not working because the mime type of .7z extension is:

```
application/x-7z-compressed
```

See this link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/7z

Comment: Ok, how can I get the path to the chosen file? Via Intent or not? How? I didn't find any samples

Comment: Don't use getEncodedPath() because this is not good if you want to open file. File may be not exists because spaces (%20) will be not decoded.